# Creating a static Settings class from inside that class but non static fields not updating

Tags: java, spring

So I have settings file for my project that looks like the following.

```
@Component
public class Settings {
    private transient final BuildProperties buildProperties;
    private static Settings settingsStatic;
    private String TF_VERSION = "EMPTY";

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Settings.class);
    private final String REPO_TF_SUBSCRIPTION = 
         "git::https://github.xxx.com/xxxxx/xxxx//subscription?ref=" + TF_VERSION);


    @Autowired
    private Settings(BuildProperties buildProperties) {
        this.buildProperties = buildProperties;
        TF_VERSION = this.buildProperties.getVersion();
        LOGGER.info("TF_VERSION is {}", this.buildProperties.getVersion());
        settingsStatic = this;
    }

    public static String getTerraformSubscriptionRepository() {
        return settingsStatic.REPO_TF_SUBSCRIPTION;
    }

}
```

The Logger outputs the correct version ie. 3.4.0, but when I call getTerraformSubscriptionRepository() it comes back with TF_VERSION=empty instead of what I expected, 3.4.0.

Can anyone explain to me why that would be happening.

Comment: Where are you calling `getTerraformSubscriptionRepository`? Are you certain that your component has been created at that point? Could you inject `Settings` instead of using static fields?

Comment: Yes I'm sure it has been created as I can see the "TF_VERSION is 3.4.0" in the logs.

What would injecting Settings look like?

Comment: Are you sure the log entry occurs before your call to `getTerraformSubscriptionRepository`?

Comment: Yes, it happens when the application loads. I then call an endpoint to call the getTerraformSubscriptionRepository, which then comes up with a TF_VERSION as empty.

Comment: REPO_TF_SUBSCRIPTION is initialised before the constructor is called, so TF_VERSION is "EMPTY".

Comment: I see what you mean, that makes sense, let me see I think I have a solution, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private String TF_VERSION = "EMPTY";
private final String REPO_TF_SUBSCRIPTION = 
     "git::https://github.xxx.com/xxxxx/xxxx//subscription?ref=" + TF_VERSION);
```

You initialize *REPO_TF_SUBSCRIPTION* with *TF_VERSION = "EMPTY"*, but because *REPO_TF_SUBSCRIPTION* is final, you can't modify it later, so it always be the same object, even if you modify *TF_VERSION*

Comment: Thanks, this is the issue, although removing the "final" doesn't fix it. 

Any ideas on how best to fix this?

Comment: did you tried to initialize it in your constructor (without the final), instead of what you were doing ?

Comment: I tried the same thing without the final, it does the same thing unfortunately.

Comment: But did you tried to initialize REPO_TF_SUBSCRIPTION in your constructor, with the updated  TF_VERSION ?

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, yeah that will work thanks!